# How to make a de-convolution layer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, deconvolution

I have written a code for deconvolution layer,

```
def deconv2d(x, W,stride):
  x_shape = tf.shape(x)
  output_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1]*2, x_shape[2]*2, x_shape[3]//2])
  decon = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, output_shape, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
  layer_shape = get_layer_shape(decon)
  print('DECONV Shape : ', layer_shape)
  return  decon
```

I have called the above function like this way,

```
deconvolution1 = deconv2d(x=cnn_layer10, W=[2,2,512,1024], stride=2)
```

getting this error,

> File "u-net.py", line 84, in 
>       obj.computation()   File "u-net.py", line 41, in computation
>       deconvolution1 = deconv2d(x=cnn_layer10, W=[2,2,512,1024], stride=2)   File "/home/shuvo/u-net/architecture.py", line 35, in
>   deconv2d
>       decon = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, output_shape, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py",
>   line 1019, in conv2d_transpose
>       if not value.get_shape()[axis].is_compatible_with(filter.get_shape()[3]):
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py",
>   line 500, in **getitem**
>       return self._dims[key] IndexError: list index out of range

My intention is to make a deconvolution layer where shape should be,
[batch_size, 36,36,1024]=>[batch_size,72,72,512].
Please help me to fix this error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input args `filter` to `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` is the weights matrix itself and not just the size of the filter.

The modified code that fixes the above problem is shown below:

```
cnn_layer10 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (10, 36, 36, 1024))

def deconv2d(x, W,stride):
   x_shape = tf.shape(x)    
   weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(W))
   output_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1]*2, x_shape[2]*2, x_shape[3]//2])
   decon = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, weights, output_shape, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')

   return  decon

deconvolution1 = deconv2d(x=cnn_layer10, W=[2,2,512,1024], stride=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   print('Decon Shape:',sess.run(deconvolution1, {cnn_layer10: np.random.random((10, 36,36,1024))}).shape)
   #Output
   #Decon Shape: (10, 72, 72, 512)
```

Note: Its better to use `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose` API, where the `filters` arg is the filter size and the weights initialization happens within.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ans, When I am trying to print the shape of decon this showing me the shape  [None, None, None, None]. why??

Comment: `tf.shape()` returns a tensor and so you can evaluate it during runtime only, as my example shows.  But you can use `x_shape = x.get_shape().as_list()` if you want to achieve what you want.

Comment: if I use x_shape = x.get_shape().as_list() then getting error for none value in tf.stack()(bach size is None) that is why getting. Is there has any other way??

Comment: If batch_size is None, then you need to use tf.shape() only

Comment: Yes, but then I will get [None,None,None,None] shape if I print the shape of decon, Thank you so much for Your ans,